# using delegate on click event to load fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

This default code is working fine:

```
$('#headerLink').fancybox({
    'ajax' : {type  : "GET" }
});
```

But I want to use delegate:

```
$('#header').delegate('#headerLink', 'click', function(){
    $.fancybox({
        'ajax' : {type : 'GET'}
    });
});
```

It appears to load at first but instead of the content it just displays this message:
*"The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."*

Then it unloads, and just redirects to the url for the link.

I tried changing the syntax to `$(this).fancybox({ ....`

I also tried using 'live' but this doesn't work either..

```
$('#headerLink').live('click', function(){
    $.fancybox({
       'ajax' : {type   : "GET" }
});
```

Any help with this really appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your code to refer to `a` element inside your delegate:

```
$('#header').delegate('#headerLink', 'click', function(){
    $(this).fancybox({             // $(this) refers to the link
        'ajax' : {type : 'GET'}
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I did try this syntax already. The only difference was it didn't load the error message before redirecting.

Comment: @grainne: Just do a `return false` to cancel the link's defautt action. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's almost working.... But the problem now is that nothing happens when the link is clicked once, it has to be clicked a 2nd time... Any idea why this might be happening?  (I'm refreshing each time to test this) I've also tried with event.preventDefault()